# Deleting an object twice

Tags: c++

I just a newbie to C++, I have a question about deleting a object in main function, my code is

```
 class aClass
 {
 public:
   int data;
   aClass* pointer=NULL;

   aClass(int x): data(x) {
     cout << "calling int constructor\n";
   }

   ~aClass() {     
       cout <<"Index " <<(*this).data<<"  calling destructor\n";
   }
};

int main()
{
  aClass ob1(1);
  aClass* pointer=&ob1;
  delete pointer;

  return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
calling int constructor
Index 1  calling destructor
Index 1  calling destructor
```

I just don't know why ob1 is deleted twice as deleting the point has already the ob1 that it is pointing to, so int function should not be able to find it and delete it again?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, undefined meaning exactly what it says.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor is called first time at line:

```
delete pointer;
```

It is called the second time when the object `ob1` is destructed automatically before the function returns.

**PS**

That code is subject to undefined behavior. You are allowed to call `delete` on a pointer only if the pointer points to memory that was returned by a call to `new`.